# How to find non-matching strings with Regex in Sublime?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have this text:

```
    <Path Fill="None"
        PathData="M244.87,363.97 L245.38,363.91 M245.38,363.91 L245.46,363.84 M245.46,363.84 L245.52,363.75 M245.52,363.75 L245.54,363.7 M245.54,363.7 L246.07,370.18 M246.07,370.18 L245.95,370.25 M245.95,370.25 L245.8,370.37 M245.8,370.37 L245.63,370.54 M245.63,370.54 L245.52,370.73 M245.52,370.73 L245.42,370.9 M245.42,370.9 L245.17,368.03 M245.17,368.03 L244.87,363.97"
        Stroke="#898989" StrokeWidth="0.5"/>
    <Path Fill="None"
        PathData="M247.4,371.21 L247.49,371.16 M247.49,371.16 L247.91,371.13 M247.91,371.13 L249.74,371.01 M249.74,371.01 L252.52,370.82 M252.52,370.82 L252.72,370.83 M252.72,370.83 L252.72,370.84 M252.72,370.84 L252.71,370.89 M252.71,370.89 L252.72,370.95 M252.72,370.95 L252.75,371.38 M252.75,371.38 L251.86,371.44 M251.86,371.44 L249.62,371.63 M249.62,371.63 L247.55,371.79 M247.55,371.79 L247.51,371.35 M247.51,371.35 L247.47,371.28 M247.47,371.28 L247.42,371.22 M247.42,371.22 L247.4,371.21"
        Stroke="#878787" StrokeWidth="0.5"/>
    <Path Fill="None"
        PathData="M246.46,372.67 L246.47,372.05 M246.47,372.05 L246.47,372.05 M246.47,372.05 L246.52,372.07 M246.52,372.07 L246.58,372.09 M246.58,372.09 L247.44,372.02 M247.44,372.02 L248.68,371.91 M248.68,371.91 L248.81,373 M248.81,373 L248.07,373.06 M248.07,373.06 L247.88,373.07 M247.88,373.07 L248.54,379.11 M248.54,379.11 L247.62,379.18 M247.62,379.18 L247.2,379.21 M247.2,379.21 L247.15,379.24 M247.15,379.24 L247.12,379.27 M247.12,379.27 L247.06,379.17 M247.06,379.17 L246.83,376.84 M246.83,376.84 L246.46,372.67"
        Stroke="#898989" StrokeWidth="0.5"/>
```

And I am trying to find and delete the paths which are not of a certain color, i.e. - #898989. I would like to use regex to find the non-matching strings.

I am trying the following:

```
.*(<Path Fill).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(?!#898989).*(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

But this returns the same as the one I would use to find the matching strings:

```
.*(<Path Fill).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(#898989).*(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

I thought the `?!` was a negative lookahead, and would exclude those strings. It seems to not change the results, though.

Any help?

Comment: Try `.*(?:<Path Fill).*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*Stroke=\"(?!#898989).*[\r\n]`

Comment: This seems to be working too - `<Path Fill((?!#878787).)*?/>`. *Please try this regex in single line mode.* Test Link: https://regex101.com/r/Cuvxos/1

Comment: @AKSingh why don't you write your first comment up as an answer? OP can't do single-line mode because the SVG paths cover several lines, and they want to select the whole thing so they can get rid of it.

Comment: @MattDMo I will after a few hours. Till then, the OP will also have mentioned any other problems he faces with my solution, if any.

Comment: @AKSingh - Thanks! That seems to be working. But... do you have an explanation why? I am befuddled why mine did not work...

Comment: @lukehawk I wrote an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many regex solutions to your problem. Lets first discuss why the regex you proposed does not work as expected.

---

### Problem

```
.*(<Path Fill).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(\r\n|\r|\n).*(?!#898989).*(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

The problem occurs at the part

```
.*(?!#898989).*(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

The regex simply says *match as much of anything as you can. After matching, check if at the current position there is no `#898989`. Then again...*.

The *match as much of anything as you can* is causing the problem. ***The first*** `.*` ***is actually capturing the whole line***.

```
        Stroke="#898989" StrokeWidth="0.5"/>
```

Then `(?!#898989)` comes into play which will succeed since after `>` there is no `#898989`. To make it obvious, change the regex to -

```
.*(?:<Path Fill).*[\r\n].*[\r\n](.*)(?!#898989).*
```

This regex does the same thing. In this regex, `(\r\n|\n|\r)` is replaced with `[\r\n]`. Nothing is being captured by the starting brackets `(?:<Path Fill)`. However, *this time the `.*` before `#898989` is surrounded by `(...)` to highlight the text being captured by it*.

Observe the yellow lines to see what is being captured by the `.*` before the `#898989`. Here is the link: https://regex101.com/r/2R54uW/1

---

### Correction

As already mentioned in the comments, the regex can be corrected by forcing the `.*` to stop at `Stroke="` and then making the position check.

```
.*(?:<Path Fill).*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*Stroke=\"(?!#898989).*[\r\n]
```

Here is another regex that does the same thing -

```
.*(?:<Path Fill).*[\r\n].*[\r\n]((?!#878787).)*/>
```

---

### Final Thoughts

Try using `[\r\n]` in place of `(\r\n|\r|\n)` since *character class is faster than alternation*.

If you have any additional doubts please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If there can not be a `<` and `>` char in the Path, you could assert that the color does not occur before the closing `/>`

```
<Path Fill(?![^<>]*#898989[^<>]*/>)[^<>]*/>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3Iigu/1)

If it should be the Stroke specifically

```
<Path Fill(?![^<>]*Stroke="#898989"[^<>]*/>)[^<>]*/>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFIKfg/1)